# use np.where to subset 3d array

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I am currently working on a satellite image, and I got a 3D array(6464,4064,3) like this

```
[[[  3.61944046e+01  -6.91377335e+01  -1.50000001e-09]
  [  3.61942863e+01  -6.91287460e+01   1.32471696e-08]
  [  3.61941681e+01  -6.91197662e+01   9.53853174e-09]
  ..., 
  [  3.11809139e+01  -3.63661194e+01   6.60078259e-09]
  [  3.11785698e+01  -3.63582687e+01   6.60078259e-09]
  [  3.11762199e+01  -3.63504028e+01   6.40588294e-09]]

 [[  3.61873817e+01  -6.91379166e+01  -1.50000001e-09]
  [  3.61872635e+01  -6.91289215e+01   1.43964334e-08]
  [  3.61871490e+01  -6.91199493e+01   1.12178125e-08]
  ..., 
  [  3.11743488e+01  -3.63688583e+01   6.63846089e-09]
  [  3.11720028e+01  -3.63610077e+01   7.23354443e-09]
  [  3.11696529e+01  -3.63531456e+01   7.43190709e-09]]

 [[  3.61803589e+01  -6.91380997e+01  -1.50000001e-09]
  [  3.61802444e+01  -6.91291122e+01   1.69292687e-08]
  [  3.61801338e+01  -6.91201324e+01   1.33426239e-08]
  ..., 
  [  3.11677856e+01  -3.63715935e+01   7.35317940e-09]
  [  3.11654358e+01  -3.63637428e+01   6.95529767e-09]
  [  3.11630821e+01  -3.63558846e+01   7.15423853e-09]]

 ..., 
 [[ -5.02645159e+00  -7.61433792e+01  -1.50000001e-09]
  [ -5.02774668e+00  -7.61361847e+01   3.38870656e-08]
  [ -5.02903891e+00  -7.61290054e+01   3.38870656e-08]
  ..., 
  [ -9.27992916e+00  -4.86378708e+01   9.09282427e-09]
  [ -9.28078461e+00  -4.86308556e+01   9.09282427e-09]
  [ -9.28179646e+00  -4.86225281e+01   7.49361462e-09]]

 [[ -5.03337288e+00  -7.61447067e+01  -1.50000001e-09]
  [ -5.03466558e+00  -7.61375122e+01   3.04580183e-08]
  [ -5.03595591e+00  -7.61303253e+01   3.48006957e-08]
  ..., 
  [ -9.28699970e+00  -4.86376190e+01   8.94025476e-09]
  [ -9.28782177e+00  -4.86308937e+01   8.15083290e-09]
  [ -9.28873920e+00  -4.86233711e+01   8.34818881e-09]]

 [[ -5.04029608e+00  -7.61460190e+01  -1.50000001e-09]
  [ -5.04158545e+00  -7.61388321e+01   3.18825499e-08]
  [ -5.04287243e+00  -7.61316452e+01   3.26812319e-08]
  ..., 
  [ -9.29387188e+00  -4.86390038e+01   8.31999980e-09]
  [ -9.29480457e+00  -4.86313744e+01   8.51963478e-09]
  [ -9.29572582e+00  -4.86238594e+01   8.71926975e-09]]]
```

which is [latitude, longtitude, radiance] * 6464rows * 4064colomns

I want to subset my interested area according to latitude and longtitude,
so I use

```
new= np.where((hh[:,:,0]<=13)& (hh[:,:,0]>=7) & (hh[:,:,1]>=-76) & (hh[:,:,1]<=-64))
```

(hh is my 3d array)

and it comes out the shape of new array is (1156142, 3),
which means it becomes a 2d array and lost its colomns and rows.

I don't know how to why and don't know how to plot the radiance figure with unknown rows and colomns.

Answer (score 0):

when `np.where` feed only one argument, [return the **tuple** condition.nonzero(), the indices where condition is True.](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

If you only want data points according to latitude and longtitude, index slicing is OK, [more detail](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Like:

```
import numpy as np

hh = np.random.randn(6464, 4064, 3)

# boolean
new_idx = (hh[:, :, 0] <= 0.13)& (hh[:, :, 0] >= 0.07) & (hh[:, :, 1] >= -0.76) & \
        (hh[:, :, 1] <= -0.64)
print(new_idx.shape)    # (6464, 4064)

# Boolean array indexing
# data points (num, latitude, longtitude, radiance)
new_arr = hh[new_idx]
print(new_arr.shape)    # (23175, 3)

# rows, cols
new_where = np.where(new_idx)
print(type(new_where))  # <class 'tuple'>
print([x.shape for x in new_where]) # [(23175,), (23175,)]
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answering. But still, the array after subsetting is a 2D array, I want to make it a 3D array, (i.e. np.shape(new_arr) --> (#no. of rows, # no. of cols, 3)), so that I can plot the radiance image using : plt.imshow(hh[,:,:0]). So can I ask for a furthur solution? Thanks a lot

Comment: ?? `np.where(new_idx,  hh,  0)`, this fix other as `0` or whatever and keep dim

Comment: ohhh, I finally figured out where the problem is!!! but now I have problem with the plot. Can I ask you how to plot the radiance with the x=latitude, y=longitude, and color of grids represent the radiance. I have tried using :plt.scatter(x=new[:,0], y=new[:,1], c=new[:,2]), however, there is no color difference.

Comment: `plt.contourf` or `plt.contour` may help.https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/51b12887938bb15f05969bde10629c175ffbbb8d/10_introduction_to_artificial_neural_networks.ipynb https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/blob/1a2c5cd925b85a3773ccab57ac413fb3c5482710/06_decision_trees.ipynb